# Connecting the Streams to a Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, server, inputstream, outputstream

I am quite fresh in programming and as a part of homework doing a chat app. It should connect to another computer via IP address, have created Server and Socket in a separate Thread, constantly listening abd writting what comes. And this is ok.
`

```
public class MyConnection extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run (){

    try (ServerSocket eServer = new ServerSocket(1300);
        Socket cn = eServer.accept();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cn.getInputStream()));)
    {
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        }
        HelpClass.writeStatus(sb.toString());
        }

    catch(IOException exc ) {Pomocna.writeStatus("An error occured: " + exc.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

`

The problem arises when I want to make method for sending message, where I have to connect my OutputStream to the socket. He cannot see the Socket for some reason. Method send() I have defined as static i one separate class, called HelpClass (not sure if this is a good practice or not), here is the method:

`

```
 public static void send(String content){
    try (BufferedOutputStream bof = new BufferedOutputStream(getOutputStream(cn))){
        byte[] b = content.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        bof.write(b);
    }

catch(IOException exc) {System.out.println("An error occured: " +     exc.getMessage());}
    }
```

`

In the moment I have been out of ideas, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you pass in `Socket cn` to solve this issue and to make it clear what you are sending.

Note: You should either
- only create one BufferedOutputStream or one BufferedInputStream per connection ever, or you are likely to see data loss.
- or don't use buffering as you don't appear to be using it anyway.

Also don't catch an exception and continue as if it didn't happen.  If you fail to write you need to close the connection. i.e. don't assume that logging it is enough. It would be simpler to not catch it at all.

This is how I might write `send`

```
public static void send(Socket sc, String content) throws IOException {
    String toSend = content+"\n"; // assume we are reading with readLine()
    sc.getOutputStream().write(toSend.getBytes(StandardCharSets.UTF8));
}
```